# Why `None` is printed in Google colab when I try to print a list?

Tags: python, printing, google-colaboratory

I have two lists, `sentences` and `tags`, which are actually list of lists.

When I try to print

```
print(sentences[1]), print(tags[1])
```

output comes as

```
['Made', 'it', 'back', 'home', 'to', 'GA', '.', 'It', 'sucks', 'not', 'to', 'be', 'at', 'Disney', 'world', ',', 'but', 'its', 'good', 'to', 'be', 'home', '.', 'Time', 'to', 'start', 'planning', 'the', 'next', 'Disney', 'World', 'trip', '.']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'loc', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'facility', 'facility', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'facility', 'facility', 'O', 'O']
(None, None)
```

I can't work out why None is getting printed.

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: @KlausD. They did, actually. It's enough to have `print(x), print(y)` in any notebook to reproduce this, regardless of what `x` and `y` are.

Answer (score 3):

Because `x, y` creates a tuple which the notebook tries to evaluate (and therefore every element in the tuple is evaluated).

Since `print` returns `None`, you are getting the tuple `(None, None)` as an output.

In order to remedy this put each `print` call on its own line instead of creating the tuple.